# How to use Conditional Compilation for Maui Application to implement unit tests?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, conditional-compilation

So I have a Net8.0 Maui application that I'm trying to shoehorn unit testing into. Normally when I've done this in the past I've added a net8.0; target, and used conditional compilation to turn off certain features to enable testing. Example here works pretty well in most situations to exclude platform specific packages and such

```
    <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Controls" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Editors" Version="23.1.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

However, the use of DevExpress itself has presented some issues as now I have XAML pages that have references to these libraries and excluding the xaml, but keeping it visible is elluding me. So I had hoped to accomplish what the Platforms folders do in regard to excluding files but keeping them visible within visual studio.

```
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0'">    
        <Compile Remove="**\MyPage.xaml.cs" />
        <MauiXaml Remove="**\MyPage.xaml" /> 
    </ItemGroup>
```

or

```
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0'">
        <None Update="**\MyPage.xaml;"> 
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">
        <None Update="**\MyPage.xaml.cs; />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I've attempted quite a few permutations of the various inclusions, compilations etc, but either the files are not listed, the files end up not compiling for the normal app, or the unit test build. Devexpress seems to be of the opinion that they arn't going to support unit testing any code with the views from what I've gathered across the web and recommended splitting the project up to only have views in one project and any unit testable code in another.

Comment: Conditional compilation for XAML files (as well as code-behind) is not officially supported, AFAIK. I've tried something similar in the past for platform-specific XAML and so far, I didn't find any good solution to this. I got a hack to sort-of work, but I won't recommend using that as it's totally impractical. Now, usually it shouldn't be necessary to remove XAML files from compilation in order to build for unit tests, unless the libraries you use don't have the `net8.0` target. Does DevExpress not target plain .NET?

Comment: Correct, DevExpress does not target plain net for the Maui libs, and when others had asked them they indicated they were not planning to do so.

Comment: That's weak and a reason for me not to use DevExpress. I mean, it's just a simple setting. In that case, I guess you should indeed place the business logic into a separate project which you can then test. That's the cleanest way.

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1208584/devexpress-packages-cannot-be-used-in-a-project-with-a-target-framework-unspecific-to-a
Supposedly they are going to fix this in the next release.

Comment: DevExpress components support plain .NET starting with v23.2.4, so you this shouldn't be an issue anymore